# What is the smallest ball containing four non-adjacent vertices of a cube?

Tags: geometry

> Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a cube. What is the smallest ball containing the regular tetrahedron $AB'CD'$?

I know that the ball with center being the center of the cube is a ball containing $A$, $B'$, $C$, and $D'$. But, how to prove that it is the smallest one?

Thanks you for any ideas!

Comment: I am confused as to what you could mean by "the smallest" such cube.   It is easy to show that there is **only one** such cube

Comment: @user247327 when I say "how to prove that it is the smallest one?" I mean "how to prove that the ball with center being the center of cube is the smallest ball cotaining A, B', C', D".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your tetrahedron (now with the correct points identified) is the regular tetahedron with side-length sqrt(2). If that is the case, then symmetry confirms that the centre of the circle coincides with the centre of the tetrahedron *and* the centre of the cube.

The distance from the centre of the cube to *any* of its vertices is sqrt(3)/2, so that must be the radius of the 'smallest' sphere or ball containing the tetrahedron.

To propose a *simmetry arguement*: If you rotate by 180 degrees about the centre normal of any face of the cube, then the vertices of the cube rotate onto themselves (that is a well understood symmetry property of any cube). Thus the equivalent vertices of the tetrahedron also rotate onto themselves. Thus the enclosing sphere *and* its centre point does not move. So the centre points of all three bodies lie at (0,0,0) (assuming the cube is the set of eight points (+/-0.5,+/-0.5,+/-0.5)). The rest follows...

Comment: yeah, but how to formalize the statement "then symmetry confirms that ..."?

Comment: Yeah, I understood. Thank you so much. 1 up vote!

Here we implicitly use two facts: 1. the smallest ball is unique in Euclidean space and 2. the intersection of n hyper-planes is a point (here n=3).

Answer (score 0):

Any ball containing all 4 points certainly must have diameter at least as large as the the maximum distance between any two points.

If I'm imagining how you are labeling the vertices correctly, then $A$ and $C'$ are opposite so the sphere you mention attains this bound.

Comment: Ah, I got a mistake in my question, the four points should be A, B', C, D'. I edited my question.